# How can Bound state energy be negative if the $V_{min}$ is positive?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, schroedinger-equation, potential-energy

We know that Energy must be negative for bound states (as the wavefunction must go to 0 at infinity) but when we are looking at potential wells, we also say that E must be greater than the minimum value of potential ($V_{min}$ ) for a normalisable solution, so don't we have a contradiction when the $V_{min}$   is positive or even 0?

I think I might've made a major mistake in my thought process but I can't figure out what that is, any insight will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicates: [Why Energy is greater than min value of Potential in Bound state?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/391446/2451) and links therein.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the potential is only defined up to an overall constant, you should be suspicious of any definitions that depend on the absolute value of $V(x)$. Thus, a statement like $E<0$ is meaningless, since only energy *differences* are physically meaningful quantities!

In general, bound states are those which have an energy less than the value of the potential at $\pm \infty$. Now, in some physical problems like the finite potential well and the hydrogen atom we *assume* that $V(x)\to 0$ as $x\to \pm \infty$, which is why it is often said that bound states have negative energy. However, it should be clear to you that this is certainly not the case in general!

Indeed, I am certain you already know of two famous counter-examples: the particle-in-a-box (the "infinite square well") and the harmonic oscillator. Both of these potentials have **only** bound states, and they certainly don't have negative energies! The fact that all their states are bound can now be explained using my earlier argument: since both these potentials blow up at $x\to\pm\infty$, *all* energies are less than $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}V(x) = V_{\pm\infty}$, and therefore all states are bound.

To answer your specific question about the potential well, in order for your potential to be a "well" you would require it to have $V_\text{min} < V_{\pm\infty}$ (since otherwise it would be something like a "top-hat" potential which would have no bound states anyway). If you *choose* $V_{\pm\infty} = 0$, then $V_\text{min}$ **must** be less than zero in order for your potential to describe a "well". You could, of course, choose $V_{\pm\infty}=V_0>0$, but in this case bound states would be those that have an energy $E<V_0$.

See also the answers to these questions: [What exactly is a bound state and why does it have negative energy?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/92244) and [Scattering vs bound states](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/9773).